# how to use 2 shotgun mics for videocam with external mic input

Tags: video, microphone-technique

I need to record an interview (2 persons) but can't use lavaliers.  What about using 2 shotgun mics (e.g. Rode Videomic pro) on tripods, wired to the external mic input of a Sony Handicam (CX580).  I.e. how to adapt 2 3.5mm stereo outputs (mono source) to one 3.5mm jack.  Or is there a way simpler solution for bidirectional recording?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have two persons in the interview, hire a boom operator with experience.
she or he will handle the audio side and you can focus on the interview.

Answer (score 0):

Your mic input can only handle one mic.  you need something like the zoom h4n to record two

Answer (score 0):

As above, your Sony Handicam is only equipped to handle one input, probably a 2.2v (switchable from the lcd menu) jack input. This will allow power to low end shotgun (condenser) mic such as the Rode Videomic and others in that range.

I'm not an expert, however, I would say that if you find that particular adapter to combine two (3.5mm) shotgun mics into one, that it would not work anyway.

Your best bet is like what the others recommend, purchase either a separate mixer/recorder or hire a boom swinger with their own equipment.

If your are finding yourself in this position frequently and with not much budget you should probably consider purchasing a separate recorder such as Zoom H4/5/6 series or Tascam DR 60d (approx. $200).

Setups like these all depend on your budget, resources and how much you spare, or borrow from others (i.e universities, or hire shops)

Good luck!